# Экранирование поискового запроса от нежелательного кода

Tags: php, экранирование

Не понимаю, как экранировать поисковый запрос, чтобы строки типа

```
8&cost%5Bfrom%5D=12%22%3E%3Cscript%3E`&cost%5Bto%5D=123123`;alert()%3C/script%3Eqweqwe%27%22asd
```

не выполняли сторонний код. Экранирую с помощью `htmlspecialchars`, но `alert()` всё равно выполняется. `strip_tags` тоже не помог.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать функцию [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php), которая заменяет все не цифро-буквенные символы знаком процента и номером в таблице символов Unicode.